# Angular velocity of a rotating drum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

In this problem, why is it that for the angular velocity at point A we take the radius as the difference between B and A, and not just the distance from A to G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of looking at this is to consider the rolling with no slipping as a combination of the translational motion of the centre of the drum relative to the ground (**$1$**) plus the rotational motion about the centre of the drum (**$2$**) as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

The resultant velocities of the drum (**$3$**) are found by vector addition.

MIT have produced a nice [animation to show this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adHN5a1LER0&index=39&list=PLnwktbKyJK0qoR75UV5SQbXA2RtrpQnyK).

In your problem you are given information about the motion of a point (**$B$**) on the circumference of the smaller drum.

[image]

You can view this as a rotation of the line **$BX$** about the contact point between the larger drum and the ground **$B$** and so get the velocity of the centre of the drum $v$  and also the angular speed of the drum $\omega$ using $\omega = \dfrac v R = \dfrac {v_{\rm B}}{R-r}$

For accelerations you will need to include the radial and the tangential components and add them to the acceleration of the centre of the drums.